# How to set align of document.documentElement.innerHTML = 'TEXT';

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, alignment

I want have code where text is created with document.documentElement.innerHTML = 'TEXT'; element, but I do not know how I can center it. Can I use CSS or is better to use any function in HTML?
I using some loops in script, but I want to set it on center of page for now..
When I trying anything do with it, everytime it failed. Cause I do not know where I have to start "aligning" the text.

```css
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
.script-class {
    width: 70px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    
    -webkit-align-content: center;
}

h1 {
    color: navy;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#page-wrap {
     width: 800px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Projekt 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_menu.css">
</head>

<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<div id="page-wrap">

<script class="script-class">
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
      console.log('Ok');
      update();
      //Code here
    }
   
    function update(){
      var delayInMilliseconds = 500; //1 second                        
      setTimeout(function() {
        //your code to be executed after 1 second
        console.log('Ok bro');
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = 'TEXT';
        new Audio('http://xehos.cz/testy/13290__schademans__pipe9.wav').play()
        reflush();
      }, delayInMilliseconds);
    }

    function reflush(){
      var delayInMilliseconds = 200; //1 second
      setTimeout(function() {
        //your code to be executed after 1 second
        console.log('Reflushed');
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = '';
        update();
      }, delayInMilliseconds);
    }
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help, 
Adam

Comment: what is the purpose of this code ??!! ... you are screwing all the html and your have only text inside body

Comment: For starters, `document.documentElement.innerHTML = 'TEXT';` will replace the entirety of your page's content with "TEXT". That's probably not what you want. There's also waaay too many irrelevant parts in your example code, half of which I have no idea what it's supposed to accomplish. I'd suggest you do some research on CSS fundamentals. MDN has pretty good materials: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: just give it a class and center the text on your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `document.documentElement.style.textAlign = “center”;` after your code should work. It accesses the elements css through JavaScript and sets `text-align` to `center`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
var wrap = document.createElement('p');
wrap.innerHTML = "TEXT";
wrap.style["text-align"] = "center";
document.body.appendChild(wrap);
```

You can also give it an ID with `wrap.id = "id"` to change the content in the `reflush` function:

```
function reflush(){
  document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML = "";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
    text-align: center
}
```

In your CSS

**EDIT**: or, inside of your JS, after you replace *everything in the document* with your text, you can do

```
document.documentElement.style["text-algin"] = "center";
```

Comment: Instant downvote with no comment. Please tell me why

Comment: I didn't vote, but you're trying to align every text in the DOM as center. The question does not ask for that

Comment: The code in the question instantly replaces the root element, the html element, with the text. If the asker had some way of including css outside of the root element, this would be the only thing that would work.

Comment: `The code in the question instantly replaces the root element` --> so there is a huge issue with the code, i don't think it's a good idea to provide centring like this because the code is bad ... we need first to fix the code then correctly use CSS

Comment: I just answered the question they asked.

Comment: The first can not work cause css colide with javascript in this.